# VS12 Debugger crashes only for IE

Tags: visual-studio-2012, internet-explorer-9

I have an MVC3 app that's been working for quite a while and today began crashing anytime I launch a debugging session with IE as the initial browser. If my initial browser is Chrome or FF - no problem. Further....if I open the site with IE _after it's been launched to one of these other browsers, no problem. The debugger's break points respond just as expected. So that's pretty strange, yes?

I can F10 without hitting any problems until the point where the browser is invoked and, up to this point, haven't been able to catch the last couple lines in VS's output windows - it crashes and restarts without giving opportunity to copy any of that output.

Event viewer shows:

```
Fault bucket 3561940412, type 5
Event Name: CLR20r3
Exception code: 0xe0434352
```

(there's more erreta if you'd like deeper details) - searching against those codes looks like it's a fairly general/generic error.

I've stepped out to the file system and deleted the .obj and .bin folders for all the projects in the solution, rebooted a couple times, and am in the process of getting on with my life cuz, as of right now, this is easy enough to work around.

<strike>I suppose i could delete windows temp files and check again.</strike> Any other thoughts?